# How can I scan another process memory to find what follows a specific string?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I want to scan the entire heap of a currently running native application through another process.

For example, I want to know what follows all the instances of the ASCII sequence "test" in this process memory (in this case I would scan for "test" and keep reading after it).

I tried to google for more information but didn't find much: I found [ReadProcessMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680553%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) which looked interesting, but how can I know the memory addresses a process has allocated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [`VirtualQueryEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366907.aspx).

If you're finding that you're accessing a lot of memory in the other process, consider using `CreateRemoveThread` ([sample code](http://win32.mvps.org/processes/remthread.html)). This will allow you to inject your own DLL into the other process and run code there directly. Once you're running code in the other process, you'll be able to access memory as normal, without needing to use `ReadProcessMemory`. (You'll still need `VirtualQuery` to determine the process's memory layout.)

Comment: Yup, winner.  The odds of finding multiple matches for "test" are good.